# Rails form redirections for new/create, edit/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 2.3.8

I'm having an issue with the actions that get rendered after an error in a form.

So I have a `posts` controller and the regular related actions, `index`, `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update`, and `show`.

Here are the actions with forms in `PostsController`:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  # other setup
end

def create
  if request.post?
    @post= Post.new(params[:post])
    # other setup for save
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully created.'
      redirect_to campaign_path(@post, :redirect => "create")
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end 
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  # other setup
end


def update
  # setup for save
  if @campaign.update_attributes(params[:post])
    flash[:notice] = 'Your post was successfully updated.'
    redirect_to :action=> "index"
  else
    render :action => "edit"
  end
end
```

And here are the forms in the views

`new.html.erb`:

```
<% form_for(@post, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  # Form fields and stuff
  <%= f.submit "Create New Post" %>
<% end %>
```

`edit.html.erb`:

```
<% form_for(@post, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  # Form fields and stuff
  <%= f.submit "Update This Post" %>
<% end %>
```

**My problem is**: If I'm on the `new` page and I make some error (e.g. leave a field empty), the views that render submit to the wrong place. So if I start out on `new` and submit unsuccessfully a bunch of times, it takes me successively through `new`, then `create`, then `edit`, then `update` actions. So the behavior is:

Start out creating a post:

Action: `new`
URI: `/posts/new`
View rendered: `new`
Successful submit goes to: `show`
Unsuccessful submit goes to: `create`

After first unsuccessful submit:

Action: `create`
URI: `/posts` **bad?**
View rendered: `new`
Successful submit goes to: `index` (this means the form is submitting to the `update` action, **bad**)
Unsuccessful submit goes to: `edit` **bad**

After second unsuccessful submit:

Action: `edit` **bad**, I shouldn't be able to get here from `new`!
URI: `/posts/[id]`
View rendered: `edit` **bad**, I shouldn't be able to get here from `new`!
Successful submit goes to: `index` through update
Unsuccessful submit goes to: `update`

After third and subsequent unsuccessful submits:

Action: `update` **bad**, I shouldn't be able to get here from `new`!
URI: `/posts/[id]`
View rendered: `edit` **bad**, I shouldn't be able to get here from `new`!
Successful submit goes to: `index`
Unsuccessful submit goes to: `update`

I'd appreciate if anyone can point me to what I'm doing wrong. If you need any additional information just ask.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the code that you are using to create your post (# setup for save).  You are probably setting @post.id which is causing your new form to submit to update instead of create.  The form_for helper checks if a record is new or not, if it is new then it submits to create, if it already exists it submits to update.

Note: You also don't need to check request.post? on your create action. The create action should always be a post request.

Comment: I've added a line into the `create` that is the gist of what i do to set up for the save, which is `@post = Post.new(params[:post])` I also do an `update_attribute`. Don't I have to call `Post.new` in order to save it? To clarify,  I don't specify `id` explicitly anywhere though I imagine one gets created automatically at some point.

Comment: If you make a call to update_attribute there is a chance that your post is getting saved there.  Your first check should be that update_attribute does not succeed - if it does then you are performing an update and not a create on your next action.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I removed the update attribute and folded the change into a `merge!` on the params hash when I make the new Post and it works as expected now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

What are your routes looking like for this?

And as Pan said, no need for that `request.post?` especially without an `else` to capture if it's not a `post?`